# Sms not working for some countries

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

There were multiple errors occurred we use OTP verification. Many customers didn't receive OTP and our business is stuck due to this issue.
One error shows as follows in the log: Unable to create record: The 'To' phone number: +91XXXXXXXX, is not currently reachable using the 'From' phone number: TWILIOFROM via SMS.

We are not able to reach #twilio support team at anyhow. Any assistance on this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

Some countries do not support alphanumeric sender IDs, so you will get that error. There is a [list of countries that do support alphanumeric IDs on the Twilio support site](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223133767-International-support-for-Alphanumeric-Sender-ID).

You have some options to improve this.

First, you need to use a fallback number to deliver the messages to the countries that don't support alphanumeric IDs. You can do this two ways.

Either, you write the code that catches the error that you've described above or you can use a [messaging service](https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/services) that has a number or multiple numbers in a number pool and also an alphanumeric ID. The messaging service will then try to use the alphanumeric sender and fallback to the number pool automatically.

On the other hand, you could take a look at [Authy which is two factor authentication as a service](https://www.twilio.com/docs/authy). It handles delivering SMS messages for you, but also allows you to use the more secure and easier to deliver app based codes.

Let me know if this helps at all.